# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T[K]'

Tags: typescript

I have this code block:

```
function sumOnValue<T, K extends keyof T>(collection: Array<T>, key: K): number {
  let result = 0;
  for (const o of collection) {
    const sample = o[key];
    if (typeof o[key] === 'number') {
      result = result + sample; // [ts] Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T[K]'.  red squigly line under sample.
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const sampleCharges: Array<ICharge> = [
  {
    AllowedAmount: 10,
  },
  {
    AllowedAmount: 15,
  },
  {
    AllowedAmount: 9,
  },
];

const resultedSum = sumOnValue(sampleCharges, 'AllowedAmount');
console.log(resultedSum);
```

As depicted in the above, I get the error from the compiler (vscode reports it as a problem) but when running the code it's fine and doesn't complain. What should I be doing here to suppress the error or to write this method 'safely via type checking'?

**The objective in a nutshell is:** Add up a given attribute within an array of `T` provided that the given attribute is a type within `T` and that the attribute is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.1+ this can be done using indexed access types. Indexed access types are compile-time checks and never make it in to your JavaScript, unlike type guards.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

```
function pickAndReduce<T>(
    collection: Array<{ [k in keyof T]: number }>,
    key: keyof T
): number
{
    let result = 0;
    for (const o of collection) {
        result = result + o[key];
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the loop could be reduced, if so desired.

```
function pickAndReduce<T>(
    collection: Array<{ [k in keyof T]: number }>,
    key: keyof T
): number
{
    return collection.reduce((total, item) => total + item[key], 0);
}
```

EDIT:

Originally I had `key: string`, as in the example, but as pointed out in a comment, this overlooks type checking on the index access. I've change it to `key: Key of T` so the function may only be invoked with keys present on the given object.

Comment: Index access skips type checking

Comment: This still doesn’t necessarily do what is desired by the original code which simply skips non-numeric elements

Comment: If you're writing your code so you can have numbers and other stuff in the same property and then sum that property ignoring anything that isn't a number, then maybe you shouldn't be using TypeScript at all. I made a guess that maybe OP wanted to ensure that those properties were indeed all numbers, rather than figure it out at runtime, since this isn't something JavaScript can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to do this -- implement a function `isNumber` that does the same `typeof` check:

```
function isNumber(x): x is number {
    return typeof x === "number";
}

function sumOnValue<T, K extends keyof T>(collection: Array<T>, key: K): number {
  let result = 0;
  for (const o of collection) {
    const sample = o[key];
    // use here
    if (isNumber(sample)) {
      result = result + sample;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this overkill? All OP needs to do is change the `if` to compare against `sample` instead of `o[key]`, eg: `if (typeof sample === "number")`. Then typescript will properly narrow `sample`'s type and the error disappears.

Comment: MVPs! to the both of you. I totally forgot about type guards... still new here. and thank you @CRice for the comment!!

Comment: This can be done using index access types instead of type guards, which is a cleaner approach because it does not add unnecessary code to the JavaScript.